# My Simple Array Is Not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The app is freezing when the array is being loaded.

Getting Error at NSString *weight line:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14904'
```

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)weightButtonPressed
{
pickerArrayHalf = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [pickerArrayHalf addObject:@"0"];
    [pickerArrayHalf addObject:@"1/2"];
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
    NSString *weight = [[pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row] stringValue];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", weight];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a string to the array:

```
[pickerArrayHalf addObject:@"0"];
```

so there's no use to later on asking the string for its stringValue:

```
[[pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row] stringValue];
```

Get rid of the call to `stringValue` (NSString does not even implement stringValue, for obvious reasons):

```
NSString *weight = [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row];
```

Further more why are you wrapping your string into a new one here?:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", weight];
```

just do this:

```
NSString *weight = [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row];
label.text = weight;
```

or even shorter:

```
label.text = [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row];
```

---

Last but not least your `pickerView :…` method is leaking `label` and not returning a UIView as expected.

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard that you like `NSString`s so I put an `NSString` inside of an `NSString` from an `NSString` that I tried to get the stringValue from.

Comment: Yeah, one better plays it safe! ;)

Comment: We could also point out that he is not returning the UILabel!

Comment: Lol, look what I had just added to my answer (that plus a leak). :)

Answer (score 3):

You stored `NSString`s in the array using `@"0"` and `@"1/2"` and `NSString` does not respond to stringValue, it is a string. Just remove stringValue from the method calls.

```
NSString *weight = [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row];
```

**Side Note:**

You are over complicating setting the text of the label. Simply do the following.

```
label.text = [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row];
```

Also you are not retuning any view in that example which should generate a warning. The last line should be

```
//I would recommend calling autorelease on the initial alloc/initWithFrame
return [label autorelease];
```